# What is this high-wing, single-propeller, possibly military plane?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I recently acquired a black & white photograph of a group of military people posed in front of an airplane.  I am seeking information about the plane, and maybe the people.

The plane is mostly obscured by the people, but it is a high-wing, single propeller plane.  The wingspan looks to be about 30 feet.  The wings are straight, not swept back.

The people are pretty clearly military, but I cannot tell from what country.  Notably(?) , there is a woman among the two dozen men.

UPDATE:

Friends have speculated that the woman is Amelia Earhart.  The Amelia Earhart Museum says no.

Most military folks say that the uniforms are not military.  They speculate that they are a delivery service or maybe an airline.

UDPATE2:

The back of the photograph has a stamped "992" in red.

Also, the photo is in a nice folder with a matte (not shown).  The matte is labelled "Fas Foto".

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe post the picture here?

Comment: Hi dkalkwarf. I cropped the image to show the relevant portion. The full image is available via the revision history if someone wants to see the album as well.

Comment: Best I can do is a J-3 Cub with the prop removed but there should be a vent hole and carb inlet screen below the crankshaft, that isn't there, so I'm not so sure.

Comment: It might be good to establish where these folks are from, but they may be posing in front of a troop carrying glider.  Perhaps part of a test flying or ferrying crew team.

Comment: @JohnK nose area looks too wide and large overall for a J-3. Looks almost like a late WW1 design. There also seems to be faint lettering on the wing, looks like 3GS. Maybe that gives people some leads

Comment: Uniforms and hair styles suggest US military

Comment: Some similarity with a [Waco CG-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waco_CG-3), but smaller.

Comment: I believe this may be a TG-5 or TG-8 US Air Force training glider. The clue is that you can just see that both wing mounts are unusually long and extend all the way down to the bottom of the fuselage. That thing on the nose is for towing. https://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled/TG-8-Glider/5257145

Comment: Maybe a dumb question:  is there anything on the back of the picture?

Comment: A couple other thoughts:  the struts go to 2/3 or 75% span down the wings, further than the Waco gliders, and the landing gear struts (esp. just right of the woman in white) look wrong for the TG-8.  Aside from what's visible of the nose, it looks very Piper Cub or L-3...which leads me back to the TG-5, if that dark circle is a tow hook.  But if it was a TG-5, I'd expect there to be an AAF or USAF roundel on the underside of the wing (to the left side of the picture) and there isn't one.

Comment: Focke-Wulf 56 possibly?

Comment: I'd add it's very likely to be a glider given the way it's tied down, something you don't normally need to do for powered aircraft. See how the tie is very similar to this one - https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/9092447 ... TG-6 is another possibility.

Comment: ... Here's a civilian one which shows underwing numbering http://legendsintheirowntime.com/LiTOT/Content/1942/Av_4209_TG6_pic_p203_W.png